# How do i find the first letter in alphabet from the input and count the input letters

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have been coding bash script by using read commands to accept the input of a series of upper case alphabetic letters, one at a time. The input ends with a 0. Find and display the first letter in alphabetic order among all the valid input letters and the count of total number of valid input letters.

if I, for example, input of D, G, T, W, Q, 3, B, 1, D, S, 0, the expected output is that:

“3 is an invalid input”

“1 is an invalid input”
“The first letter in alphabet of all inputs is B”

“You have entered 8 valid letters.”

Here is some my code and please let me know what do I gotta fix

```
#!/bin/bash
IV=()
loop=-1
c=Z
ac=0

while [ $loop -gt 0] || [ $loop -t 0]
do
echo "Enter an uppercase Alphabet"
read b
if [[ $b = [A-Z] ]]
then
      ac=`expr $ac +1`
      if [ $b \< $c ]
      then
              c=$b
      fi

elif [ $b = "0" ]
then
       loop=`expr $loop +1`
       for i in "${IV[@]}"
       do
       echo $i "is an invalid input"
       done
       echo "The first letter in Alphabetical order of all input is" $c
       echo "You have entered" $ac "valid letters."

else
       IV[@]=$b
fi
done
```

So, My problem is that if i input invalid string or int, the output is like 
"IV[@]:  bad array subscript"

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with the posted code? What doesn't work for you? Are you looking for a review? Then perhaps better suited over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

As a start, change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x` and look at the output...

Comment: ahh sorry for that. My problem is that if i input invalid string or int, the output is like " IV[@]:  bad array subscript"

Comment: That's because you cannot do `IV[@]=$b`. The `@` specifier allows you to list all elements, but it cannot be used as an `lvalue` for assignments as you have it. Why `ac=`expr $ac +1`? A simple ((ac++)) is all that is needed. `expr` works, but *s l o w l y ...*. What is `[ $b \< $c ]`? Have you run your code through [**ShellCheck.net**](http://www.shellcheck.net/) yet?

Comment: `[ $b \< $c ]`  is to sort order of alphabet that I input and its work fine, but thanks for letting me know about ShellCHeck.net I'll run my code there

Comment: Thanks for helping me out all now its finely work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code is close to doing what you want it to do. With a few adjustments, and a convenience *parameter expansion* to turn all input to upper-case, you can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a IV   # invalid values
c=Z
ac=0

while :
do
    echo "Enter an uppercase Alphabet"
    read b
    b="${b^^}"
    if [[ $b = [A-Z] ]]
    then
        ((ac++))
        [ "$b" \< "$c" ] && c="$b"
    elif [ "$b" -eq "0" ]
    then
        for i in "${IV[@]}"
        do
            echo $i "is an invalid input"
            done
            echo "The first letter in Alphabetical order of all input is" $c
            echo "You have entered" $ac "valid letters."
        break;
    else
        IV+=("$b")
    fi
done
```

**note:** I removed the `loop` value altogether and replaced it with a simple `break` which looks like a cleaner implementation of your conditionals.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash letterseries.sh
Enter an uppercase Alphabet
d
Enter an uppercase Alphabet
g
Enter an uppercase Alphabet
t
Enter an uppercase Alphabet
w
Enter an uppercase Alphabet
q
Enter an uppercase Alphabet
3
Enter an uppercase Alphabet
b
Enter an uppercase Alphabet
1
Enter an uppercase Alphabet
d
Enter an uppercase Alphabet
s
Enter an uppercase Alphabet
0
3 is an invalid input
1 is an invalid input
The first letter in Alphabetical order of all input is B
You have entered 8 valid letters.
```

That provides your expected output, and the primary change (other than stylistically with `(( .. ))` and `b="${b^^}"` to change to upper-case, the code is largely what you had. The primary issue was your

```
 IV[@]=$b
```

Which is invalid syntax. It appears you intended:

```
    IV+=("$b")
```

to store each of the values of `"$b"` in the indexed array `IV`.

Look things over and let me know if I addressed your problem. If not, just drop a comment and I'll help further.